# how to tag a folder in a hidden directory in OS X

Tags: macos, finder, tags

In OS X is there a way to tag a folder inside of a hidden directory or tag the hidden directory itself?

As a workaround I create aliases of those folders and place them somewhere visible and tag the aliases, but tagged aliases have to be opened in their own Finder windows in order to see their contents, Finder column view doesn't show their contents.

Answer (score 0):

Save this script as an app.

Double-click it to show invisible files.
Tag as necessary.
Double-click again to hide invisibles.

```
set newHiddenVisiblesState to "YES"
try
    set oldHiddenVisiblesState to do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles"
    if oldHiddenVisiblesState is in {"1", "YES"} then
        set newHiddenVisiblesState to "NO"
    end if
end try
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles " & newHiddenVisiblesState


tell application "Finder"
    set theWindows to every Finder window
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in theWindows
        set this_item to item i of theWindows
        set theView to current view of this_item
        if theView is list view then
            set current view of this_item to icon view
        else
            set current view of this_item to list view

        end if
        set current view of this_item to theView
    end repeat
end tell
```

This won't change immediate visibility on the Desktop itself, only Finder windows.

To find hidden files in Spotlight, you need to specify in your search parameters…

[image]

Comment: tagged hidden files don't appear in the Finder view for that tag

Comment: …because they're hidden. Spotlight doesn't search hidden folders by default, you have to specify in your search parameters. Adding to answer to provide pics

Comment: hmm… actually, that won't work either, so long as they are actually hidden

Comment: yeah, I would like to tag and see either the invisible directory itself or any of its subdirectories, but I guess it's inherent to the tags views to ignore hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler than you think!

1. Create a shortcut of the folder you would like to tag
2. Move the shortcut to somewhere outside the hidden folder
3. Tag the shortcut.

it's done.